# ELK stack installation and configuration

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

I have tried to install ELK stack on centOS 6.6.

I cannot continue and stuck at curl "http://localhost:9200/_search?pretty"

Could not connect to host..

http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.0/tutorials/getting-started-with-logstash

Comment: Is Elasticsearch running?  Is it running on localhost?  Can you telnet/nc to that port from your machine?

Comment: I can putty in the machine. I disabled selinux , I also did iptables with port 9200.iptables -i INPUT -p tcp --dport 9200 -j ACCEPT

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide much information to base an answer on, so it is a bit difficult to give you any specific help. You should start over with the installation, carefully stepping through each requirement. I would suggest the following guide as a starting point, which includes a few troubleshooting tips: [How to Set Up the ELK Stack- Elasticsearch, Logstash and Kibana](http://knowm.org/how-to-set-up-the-elk-stack-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana/)
.

If you edit your question to explain exactly where you are stuck, I can modify my answer to address any specifics.